# startService() works fine with API 17 but Crashs the app with higher APIs

Tags: android, android-studio, service

I'm trying to make a bubble that floats in the home screen, similar to the one in the Messenger app, and if i install it on a physical device with android version 4.2.2 (API 17), it works just fine, but when i installed it on another physical devices (android version 4.4 (API 19) / android version 5.1 (API 21)), the app installed and run fine, but when i call the function `startSevice()`, the app Crashs and says that my application has stopped.

Here are the codes :

|

**Manifest.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mousa.issa.alfhaily.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".Bubble"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

|

**Bubble.java** (the service) :

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Bubble extends Service{
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView chatHead;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){return null;}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        chatHead = new ImageView(this);
        chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.floating);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SingleTapConfirm());

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;
        params.alpha = 0.5f;
        LINE : 25 --> windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);

        try{
            chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
                private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
                private int initialX;
                private int initialY;
                private float initialTouchX;
                private float initialTouchY;

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                        Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(Bubble.this, MainActivity.class);
                        dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(dialogIntent);
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        switch (event.getAction()){
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                initialX = paramsF.x;
                                initialY = paramsF.y;
                                initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                                initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                                break;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                                try{
                                    if(event.getRawX() >= MainActivity.ScreenSize.x / 2){
                                        paramsF.x = MainActivity.ScreenSize.x - 80;
                                    }else{
                                        paramsF.x = 0;
                                    }
                                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead , paramsF);
                                }catch (Exception e){
                                    Toast.makeText(Bubble.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                                break;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                                paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                                windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead , paramsF);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }catch(Exception ignored){}
    }

    private class SingleTapConfirm extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event){
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
    }
}
```

|

**When i call the service :**

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Bubble.class));
```

|

**Error Log :**

> 05-08 12:45:11.499 10310-10310/mousa.issa.alfhaily.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: mousa.issa.alfhaily.myapplication, PID: 10310
>                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service mousa.issa.alfhaily.myapplication.Bubble: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@485bcc0 -- permission denied for this window type
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3817)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:223)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1882)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                               Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@485bcc0 -- permission denied for this window type
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:881)
>                                                                                  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:337)
>                                                                                  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:109)
>                                                                                  at mousa.issa.alfhaily.myapplication.Bubble.onCreate(**Bubble.java:25)**
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3807)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1882) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: please also add error log

Comment: @Pravin , I added the error log, sorry for being late.

Comment: @Pravin , I solved the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem and now it's working perfectly, and it was from the permission, so the problem is started even from API 21, because no matter what i try, only adding the code above solved the problem, also **the physical device that i tried the app on, runs on the API 21**, and in the app manager for my app i don't see the permission that i added in the Manifest, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>`, it completely ignores it:

From Android 5.1(version 21) there are big changes in permission model that forces developers to request permissions at run time. 
Not all developers knows about that and this cause such exceptions like:

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@86fb55b -- permission denied for this window type

**or**

> java.io.FileNotFoundException·/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/com.example.app/main.1.com.example.app.obb: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

So even if you put the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>` in the Manifest.xml, you still want to ask for that permission when you start the app.

You can do it like that :

```
public static int OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 1234;

public void someMethod() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
            Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE) {
        // SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission not granted...
    }
}
```

Hope someone will find that useful.

Comment: Wrong. New permissions model is implemented from Android 6 (API 23) and are profusely detailed and documented.

Comment: But i did it and it solved the problem and it was from the permission, so the problem is started even from API 21, because no matter what i try, only adding the code above solved the problem, also the physical device that i tried the app on, runs on the API 21, and in the app manager for my app i don't see the permission that i added in the Manifest, so what you explanation about that?